# Python, how to apply this formula to every line in the database so each line gives a different value rather than the same one for each year

Tags: python, numpy, random, jupyter-notebook

This is my code.  It returns only one value for each 2001, 2002, 2003 etc.  I would rather it returned different ones.  Would axis -1 work and if so where do I put it?

```
# Define a function to map the values 
def set_value(row_number, assigned_value): 
    return assigned_value[row_number] 

#Create the dictionary 
year_dictionary ={'2001' : np.random.randint(1,202335), '2002' : np.random.randint(1,188846), 
                  '2003' : np.random.randint(1,175357), "2004" : np.random.randint(1,161868), 
                  "2005" : np.random.randint(1,148379), "2006": np.random.randint(1,134890), 
                  "2007" : np.random.randint(1,121401), "2008" : np.random.randint(1,107912), 
                  "2009" :np.random.randint(1,94423), "2010" :np.random.randint(1,80934), 
                  "2011" :np.random.randint(1,67445), "2012" :np.random.randint(1,53956), 
                  "2013" :np.random.randint(1,40467), "2014" :np.random.randint(1,26978), 
                  "2015" :np.random.randint(1,13489)} 


# Add a new column named 'mileage' 
df5['mileage'] = df5['year'].apply(set_value, args =(year_dictionary, ))
```

Here's the code to create a sample of `df5`:

```
df5 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["year", "fuel", "status", "sex", "licence_type", "mileage"])

# Populate the data with the number of cars per year.
df5['year'] = np.random.choice(["2001", "2002","2003","2004","2005","2006","2007","2008","2009",2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015], p=[0.004, 0.02, 0.044, 0.087, 0.149, 0.187, 0.221, 0.091, 0.012, 0.031, 0.009, 0.036, 0.013, 0.083, 0.013], size=(100))

# Populate the Fuel column with petrol and diesel
df5['fuel'] = np.random.choice(['petrol', 'diesel'], 100, p=[0.24, 0.76])  

# Populate the status column 
df5['status'] = np.random.choice(["pass", "fail", "incomplete"], 100, p=[0.36, 0.63, 0.01])

# Populate the sex column
df5['sex'] = np.random.choice(['male', 'female'], 100, p=[0.53, 0.47])

# Populate licence_type column
df5['licence_type'] = np.random.choice(["full", "learner"], 100, p=[0.92, 0.08])

print (df5)
```

Comment: can you copy/paste your whole dataframe ?

Comment: I have tested your code. It is giving different values for mileage against each year.

Answer (score 1):

change your year_dictionary to

```
year_dictionary ={'2001' : 202335, '2002' : 188846, '2003' : 175357, "2004" : 161868, "2005" : 148379, "2006": 134890, "2007" : 121401, "2008" : 107912, "2009" :94423,"2010" :80934, "2011" :67445, "2012" :53956, "2013" :40467, "2014" :26978, "2015" :13489}
```

and set_value function to

```
def set_value(row_number, assigned_value):
    return np.random.randint(1,assigned_value[row_number])
```

Comment: It worked beautifully.  Thank you so much for this.  I have spent the last 3 days trying to get this right.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare the dictionary it is declared once (it means the random ints were once in the declaration phase and they won't change after). So even if you call your function for a specific key (ex: '2001') it will return the same value that was randomly generated in the instantiation.

So you must update the values each time you want a newly randomly generate dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I understand it a bit better now.